# Calculating a conditional sum in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

[Google Sheet with Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG1dy.png)
I've created a Google Sheet which has 3 product prices based on quantity ordered (1 x jar (`A3`), 2 x jars (`B3`), 3+ jars (`C3`) and I'm struggling to create a formula which will calculate the price based on the quantity entered in the "`D`" column.

I tried a multiple "`IF`" statement like `= IF(D8 = 1, SUM(D8*A3), IF(D8 = 2, SUM(D8*B3), IF(D8 >= 3, SUM(D8*C3))))`, but it doesn't work. I'm thinking that maybe I need an "`ARRAYFORMULA`", but I can't find any examples for inspiration.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result? You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform).

Comment: Try this within your sheet (as in screenshot) & see what happens. Select `Column_E` and set **Format** > **Number** > **Automatic**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your sheet would look like this since no data was provided about the Google Sheet.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us4xB.png)

You may use the following formula to accomplish what you'd like based on the `IF` statement that you have provided:

### SHEET FORMULA

```
=IF(D8<2, D8*A3, IF(D8<3, D8*B3, D8*C3))
```

### OUTPUT

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBirX.gif)

### REFERENCE

- [IF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: Hi Saddles, thank you for your help, it's really appreciated. I've used that formula (adjusted to =IF(D6<2, D6*A3, IF(D6<5, D6*B3, D6*C3)) to allow for tweak in quantities) but it seems to always use the C3 figure  - I've added an image to my original post to better illustrate what I mean. Not sure why, your output example worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad that the formula helped you out!

I replicated the data from your photo and the computation seemed to work fine for me. I tried troubleshooting the concern you're getting; try doing this as well:

Change the format of all the numbers to automatic first to be safe and then to "British Pound Sterling" since that's the currency based on your screenshot. I can also recommend trying another Google Sheet with the same formula to see if it's a hiccup within the one you're using. If the same issue persists, let's try to work on what could be causing the issue.

Comment: Your formula was perfect, the problem was that the quantities column was not formatted as a number - rookie mistake! Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: I'm happy to have helped out!

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are using in your sample spreadsheet should work.  The FALSE parameter in your IF formula is getting evaluated, however, which leads me to believe that the "numbers" in D6:D are being read as strings, not numbers.

If you are populating D6:D column with a formula, you can wrap the formula in `VALUE()`.  You might need to make it an `IF` statement to that you do not get 0's down the whole column.

Here are two Array Formulas you can try:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(D6:D=0,,D6:D=1,A3,D6:D<5,D6:D*B3,D6:D>=5,D6:D*C3))

[image: Screenshot1]

Here is another:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(D6:D=0,,D6:D=A2,A3,D6:D<C2,D6:D*B3,D6:D>=C2,D6:D*C3))

For this option, you would need to change A2:C2 to numbers so that they can be compared to the numbers in D6:D.

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Codedabbler - you were right about some of the number entries not being corrected formatted. I’ve now fixed the Quantity row and the formula is working perfectly. Hiding the 0s is a nice touch, so I’ll try that too.